# Хранение и восстановление 7 блоков с текстбоксами ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть 7 div'ов состоящих из Кнопки и ТекстБокса. По нажатии на кнопку запускается вот такой обработчик, где определяется какая из клавиш была нажата и какой ТБ восстанавливать, эта же функция вызывается в обратном цикле при postback с  параметром refresher true для каждого div'a. 
Проблема: при добавлении текстбоксов во второй список и далее их содержание восстанавливается неверно. В чем может быть причина?

```
protected void plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (((Button)sender).ID)
    {
        case "p":
            switch_ids(provider, provider_value, "provider", pr_count, false);
            break;
        case "t":
            switch_ids(business, work_value, "work", work_count, false);
            break;
        case "good":
            switch_ids(goods, goods_value, "goods", goods_count, false);
            break;
        case "tc":
            switch_ids(contact, conn_value, "connection", types_count, false);
            break;
        case "m":
            switch_ids(markets, market_value, "market", market_count, false);
            break;
        case "ch":
            switch_ids(routes, chann_value, "channel", route_count, false);
            break;
        case "con":
            switch_ids(contestors, conn_value, "contestors", contest_count, false);
            break;
        case "r":
            switch_ids(resources, res_value, "resources", res_count, false);
            break;
    }
}

void switch_ids(HtmlGenericControl table, TextBox tb, string key, int count, bool refresher = true)
{
    if (!refresher)
    {
        ((List<string>)ViewState[key]).Add(tb.Text);
        table.Controls.Add(new TextBox { CssClass = "td", Text = tb.Text});
    }
    else
    {
        table.Controls.Add(new TextBox { CssClass = "td", Text = ((List<string>)ViewState[key])[count] });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не забывайте присваивать уникальные ID каждому контролу.

```
void switch_ids(HtmlGenericControl table, TextBox tb, string key, int count, bool refresher = true)
{
    if (!refresher)
    {
        ((List<string>)ViewState[key]).Add(tb.Text);
        table.Controls.Add(new TextBox { ID=key+count+"created", CssClass = "td", Text = tb.Text});
    }
    else
    {
        table.Controls.Add(new TextBox { ID = key + count + "refreshed", CssClass = "td", Text = ((List<string>)ViewState[key])[count] });
    }
}
```